# Is it possible to resize a DataGridView column as the user is typing?

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I have the DataGridView's AutoSizeColumnModes property set to AllCells, but the column doesn't actually resize until the user is done editing the cell.  I tried using the cell's EditingControl's KeyPress event to call the DataGridView's AutoResizeColumns() method, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, by scripting the `CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged` event to immediately commit the edits while typing:

```
private void dataGridView1_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (dataGridView1.IsCurrentCellDirty)
       dataGridView1.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.CurrentCellChange);
}
```